Suspicious transactions

After each transaction, I can see these additional transactions, what are they?
When I hover over the information icon, I can see these transactions are initiated by another address.

Could you provide a link to the address/transactions on etherscan? It looks like you are viewing ERC20 token transfers from/to an address, but some token transfers appear to be using different versions of the ARB token. Fake versions of existing tokens are a common scam that has been used for quite a while. But, without seeing more of the tx details it's hard to tell exactly what is happening.

https://arbiscan.io/address/0xe9be1055cc7d88ae6ea75a5a7e5c35fc57dae7cc#tokentxns

The "suspicious" transactions you are seeing are all function calls to an unverified smart contract.

Looking at the transaction details, we can see that fake ARB tokens are exchanged for fake USDT tokens multiple times. Based on this, either a user is experimenting and testing things on Arbitrum mainnet for some reason, or, these fake token contracts are being used to scam users.

Deploying tokens that have an identical name and symbol as an existing token is a common tactic used by scammers to mislead and confuse people. For example, if I want to swap 0.1 ETH for USDT, I might accidentally buy some of the fake USDT. Once you've purchased the fake tokens, the liquidity is probably withdrawn programmatically so you can't exchange your fake USDT back for ETH.
When dealing with unverified smart contracts, you should never interact with them since you don't know what will happen. Recently I made a thread about another token scam called Ethereum Games, or ETHG. The creator of this ETHG token mass distributed tokens to as many addresses as possible, then they provided some liquidity for the token, so that you are lead to believe you can exchange the ETHG for something real, like ETH or USDT. However, once you try to call approve() or even transfer() on the ETHG smart contract, any real tokens you hold will probably be stolen.
